# Accessing local svn repositories via Composer.json without supplying login credentials in clear text

Tags: php, svn, composer-php

Included in my composer.json file are packages of 'private' local svn repositories. Each source url includes the svn username and password.

As the projects get deployed on different servers I don't want to have the svn login credentials available in plain text.

Is there another way to do this? I dont mind having to type the login details in each time the update is ran.

Below is an example of the composer.json file is in:

```
{
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "localpackage/localpackage1",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "source": {
            "url": "http://<username>:<password>@<ip_address>/local-package1/tags/",
            "trunk-path": "trunk",
            "branches-path": "branches",
            "tags-path": "tags",
            "type": "svn",
            "reference": "0.0.1"
        }
    }

},
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "localpackage/localpackage2",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "source": {
            "url": "http://<username>:<password>@<ip_address>/local-package2/tags/"
            "trunk-path": "trunk",
            "branches-path": "branches",
            "tags-path": "tags",
            "type": "svn",
            "reference": "0.0.1"
        }
    }

},
],
"require": {
    "localpackage/localpackage1" : "0.0.1",
    "localpackage/localpackage2" : "0.0.1"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify it, composer should prompt you at install/update for the password.